# Not able to parse JSON with NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Not able to parse JSON receiving error NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
My JSON is properly validated and is utf-8 encoded. I am using this code

```
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) ->  Void in
    print(data)
    do {
    let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[NSJSONReadingOptions()]) as? [String: AnyObject]
    print(jsonDictionary)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
})
dataTask?.resume()
```

Comment: And is your JSON really a Dictionary at top level or a NSArray? Could you show your JSON?

Comment: its an Array but I also tried [AnyObject] instead of [String: AnyObject]

Comment: yes, I am using swift 2

Comment: You should add tag to `swift2` for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is collection type `[AnyObject]` not type `[String: AnyObject]`. See code below.

```
let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? [AnyObject]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please let me know your result :p

Comment: Can you share your `json`?

Comment: @Sumit Oberoi Just update my answer. Please, try again!

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfectly working for me did a little refactor to make it easier to read and added an URL for example :

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.ipify.org?format=json")!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, _, _) in
    print(data)
    do {
        let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[])
        print(jsonDictionary)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

(This code is written in Swift 2.0)

It gives the following output : (I removed the type casting to be sure to get something)

```
Optional(<7b226970 223a2239 322e3130 332e3130 362e3838 227d>)
{
    ip = "92.103.106.88";
}
```

So this must be coming from the data you are parsing. Can't you just give it to us so we can try to find what's wrong ?

Comment: Just tried my code with your URL and it worked… https://www.dropbox.com/s/rche6d4yz94ije1/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-07-29%2011.47.19.png?dl=0

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: can you share your code, if we convert data to string it is working